# Removing overlap between convex hulls

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

In two dimensions, we are given two sets of points A and B and their respective convex hulls C_A and C_B. Assume that C_A and C_B overlap.

What is the best algorithm to find the *minimal* set that must be removed from A+B such that the resulting pair of convex hulls no longer overlaps?

I am sure this a known problem but cannot find a reference anywhere.

Comment: Minimal (i.e., if you add any of the removed points back the hulls overlap) or minimum (i.e., as many points as possible are retained)?

Comment: Hmm in these terms, I meant minimum - delete fewest points.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the best algorithm is, but I came up with an O((n+m)^2) algorithm.

Assume that all points are different. Otherwise, you need to modify the algorithm.

If two convex hulls don't intersect, there exists a line that completely separates these convex hulls. And there is also a line that separates them with only one point lying on the line. Therefore, proceed as follows:

1. For each point P of the two sets:
2. Consider the lines passing through P and all the other points.
3. Sort those lines by angle around the selected point and remember the number of points of A and B lying on the positive side of the line. You will have 3 arrays `angles`, `countsA` and `countsB` of size k < n+m.
4. Consider the angles in-between those angles (in the middle or not exactly). You will get an array `angles2` of size k.
5. Iterating through the array `angles` count the number of points of each set lying on each side of the line going through P with an angle `angles2[i]`: `nA1`, `nA2`, `nB1`, `nB2`.
6. Select the minimum value of `min(nA1+nB2, nA2+nB1)`.
7. End for.
8. Take the minimum of the found values.

There is no need to compute `angles2`, you can use the values of `countsA` and `countsB` and update iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

Using swipe line technique you can mark every point is it belong C_A or C_B.  That points which are belong to both must be excluded.
Do 2 rounds for every hull independently.
Sort all segments by x.
Sort all points by x.
Now move your scan line from left to right.
For every point see is it between segments from top and bottom. Mark point as belong to hull or not.

Repeat for other hull.

Merge your result.